# How do I run kubernetes on mac os High Sierra using docker (not vagrant or virtualbox)?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to run a kubernetes cluster on mac os for some prototyping using docker (not vagrant or virtualbox).

I found the instructions online at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md but the instructions are 3 years old (Oct 2015).
The instructions refer to boot2docker but the present version of docker on mac (Docker Community Edition v 18.06.1-ce-mac73) doesn't have boot2docker.

Can you point me to the latest instructions?

Comment: The kubernetes startup script from the distro can create a mainly containerized deployment. You will have to combine that script (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/kube-up.sh) with the boot2docker to get a working version it looks like. Not a straightforward action (I advice just to use a linux box or a cloud based deployment, much faster to get you going)

Comment: Thanks @Norbert van Nobelen. boot2docker has been deprecated and no longer ships with the latest docker on mac :(

Comment: Oops! you are pointing us to release 1.0 . We are now in k8s v1.12 and 1.13 is on the way.

Answer (score 2):

Since 2015, everything has been move to the [Kubernetes website GitHub repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/website).

The full installation/process page is now at [`kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/).

And since [issue 7307](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/7307), a Kubernetes installation on MacOs would no longer use xHyve, but, as [stated in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/):

> macOS: [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion), or HyperKit.

Answer (score 2):

Current Docker for Mac has Kubernetes included, just enable it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers.

As of this writing, use [minikube with the Hyperkit](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/drivers.md#hyperkit-driver) driver.

As stated on the link:

> The Hyperkit driver will eventually replace the existing xhyve driver